# How can I set a unique default post category for each user in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to be able to create a few users in my Wordpress site, where **each of the users *per default* post to different specified categories** when they publish new posts.

I have tried to figure out how to do this, but haven't found neither an obvious php snippet nor a plugin that can help me with this.

Do you have any idea or solution for this?

**Two examples:**

1. When "Frida" logs in and post a post I want this to be published to "Makeup and life", without her needing to choose that category.
   **So user Frida's default category is "Makeup and life"**
2. When "Michael" posts a post I want this to be published to the "Car and fun" category, without the need for him to choose so. **So user Michael's default category is "Car and fun"**

Does it exist some kind of taxonomy php snippet I can use for this, or something that ties into the user's ID and post category ID?

Can I for instance use a php snippet that says something like this?

"Frida" is user ID 2,
"Michael" is user ID 3,
"Makeup and life" is catID 3,
"Car and fun" is catID 9

```
If userID = "2", then post category is catID = "3"
If userID = "3", then post category is catID = "9"
etc
```

I have searched both in StackOverflow and in Google and not found a solution to this. I might use the wrong search query/ wordings.

This is the most close I have come to a solution, but I really not understand what to tweak to get it to work like I want to. I am not savvy in neither php nor WP's code. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89057/set-default-category-to-username

Code from there:

```
add_action('admin_init','set_user_default_cat_wpa89057');
function set_user_default_cat_wpa89057(){
    global $current_user; 
    if ( isset($current_user) ) {
        update_option( 'default_category',  $current_user->user_login);
    }
}
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733882/how-to-use-get-current-user-id-in-wordpress):

```
function hf_Function(){
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 

    if ($user_ID == 0) {
        // The user ID is 0, therefore the current user is not logged in
        return; // escape this function, without making any changes
    }

    // Run your SQL queries here (using WordPress DB class)
    global $wpdb;
    // $wpdb->query($sql);
}
add_action('init', 'hf_Function');
```

How can I use these the best way, or get what I want to work?

I probably butcher the code totally here, but am I onto something?

You who know coding, how whould I write this code so it works as intended, and exactly where should I place it?

```
add_action('admin_init','set_user_default_cat_wpa89057');
function set_user_default_cat_wpa89057(){
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 

    if ($user_ID == 0) {
        // The user ID is 0, therefore the current user is not logged in
        return; // escape this function, without making any changes
    }
    if ($user_ID == 2) {
        update_option( 'default_category',  '3';
    }
    if ($user_ID == 3) {
        update_option( 'default_category',  '9';
    }

}
```

Thank you for helping out. This is above my knowledge, but at least I try to understand :-)

Additional code (added to a comment, but didn't show in an easy to read fashion):

```
function set_default_category_for_users( $default_category, $post ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( $user_id === 3 ) {
        return 7;
    } elseif ( $user_id === 2 ) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return $default_category;
    }
}
add_filter( 'default_category', 'set_default_category_for_users', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Set each user's default category in usermeta not options by adding the option to change it on the user admin page. Your code should not have a list of one if statement per user.

Comment: @Popnoodles, thank you. I am not sure how to do that. Do you mean I should use if else else else etc? 

Will this work:
`function set_default_category_for_users( $default_category, $post ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( $user_id === 3 ) {
        return 7;
    } elseif ( $user_id === 2 ) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return $default_category;
    }
}
add_filter( 'default_category', 'set_default_category_for_users', 10, 2 );`

Sorry for the messed up code. Not sure how to get it to show properly in a comment...

Comment: I updated the original post with that code in the bottom. Easier to read.

Comment: no there should be no `if $user_id === n` at all. You should add a section in user admin to save their category using `add_action('edit_user_profile', 'my_user_admin')` and `add_action('profile_update', 'save_my_user_admin')`. In `my_user_admin` you would output a drop down select of categories, with the one in their setting as `selected`. In `save_my_user_admin` you would save the category id using `update_user_meta`. Where your if else currently exists you would use  `get_user_meta` to get that category id

Comment: Use save_post and wp_set_post_terms to add your taxonomy.